# Problem uploading file to Azure Machine Learning workspace from Azure DevOps

Tags: python, azure-devops, cloud, azure-cli, azure-machine-learning-service

I need help with a problem I am facing. I am trying to transfer or upload a file called train.py that is hosted in the Azure DevOps repository to an Azure Machine Learning workspace, specifically to a folder called "gs" in the Azure Machine Learning Notebooks environment.

My current approach has been to create a pipeline in Azure DevOps with a series of tasks, but I've hit a roadblock that I can't overcome. Here's what I've tried:

Pipeline Tasks:

Use Python 3.6: I've ensured that the environment is configured with Python 3.6.

Install Azure ML CLI: I've added the task to install the Azure Machine Learning CLI.

Upload files: This is where the problem arises. I have configured the subscription, the resource group name and the workspace name where I want to upload the file. My command in this task looks like this:

```
az ml file upload -w $(azureml.workspaceName) -g $(azureml.resourceGroup) --source-path "train.py" --destination-path "Users/luis/train.py"
```

In addition, I have set the Working Directory to match the location of the train.py file.

I have tried to run the pipeline with the above configuration, but I encounter an error that says:

**##[error]Script failed with error: Error: Unable to locate executable file: '/home/vsts/work/_temp/azureclitaskscript1692061987495.bat'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
**

I was expecting the train.py file to load successfully into the "gs" folder in my Azure Machine Learning workspace. However, I am confused about how to resolve this issue and am not sure what I should modify or add in my configuration to accomplish this.

Any suggestions or guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. If you need more information, please don't hesitate to ask. thanks in advance!